# How to download eclair sources with repo

Tags: android, git, repository

I've tried both of the following:

```
repo init -u git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/manifest.git -b android-2.1
repo init -u git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/manifest.git -b eclair
```

Both give the same output:

```
Getting repo ...
   from git://android.git.kernel.org/tools/repo.git
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

fyi I tried again at 0700 uk time and worked fine this time

```
$ repo init -u git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/manifest.git -b eclair
Getting repo ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be a [server issue](http://groups.google.com/group/repo-discuss/browse_thread/thread/8ad44c12a3a63a82):

> FWIW, I was able to work around this by hacking my `/etc/hosts` to point 
>   `android.git.kernel.org` to the IP address of `android2.git.kernel.org`.